# php scrape and output everything that has a type of tag, h1, p, etc

Tags: php, xpath, scrape

I'm close to knowing how to do this, but I only know how to grab specific things from a given h1 tag named _____ for ex. I'm quite new to php, so I'm not totally sure how to rig it. What I'd like to see if I can figure out, is for a random website, how to scrape and output EVERYTHING with for ex, an h1 tag.

This is what I'm able to do so far. It probably just requires a small modification. Thoughts? Thank you.

this scrapes everything from an < a > tag named "world-market". What I can't quite figure out without breaking the code, is how to simply output ANYTHING in a < a > tag

```
<?php 

 $doc = new DOMDocument;

// foriegn stocks
 $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;


 $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
  $doc->recover = true;

 $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.money.cnn.com/data/markets/');

 $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

  $query = "//a[@class='world-market']";

  $entries = $xpath->query($query);
 foreach ($entries as $entry) {
 echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Use PHPQuery, a Jquery like implementation for Dom Document and selectors, it's very easy to use and works great.

Comment: here is a decent tutorial on it, though I am sure you can find others too,  https://www.sitepoint.com/server-side-html-handling-using-phpquery/

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742687/php-scrapping-and-outputting-a-specific-value-or-number-in-a-given-tag/44753597#44753597. Happy to help if you are confused using Xpath to select the required element. Hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything for a given tag, is it not sufficient to simply query "//a"? Or "//a/text()"? If you are looking for the href part, you could try "//a/@href".

Good luck.