# php scraping and outputting a specific value or number in a given tag

Tags: php, xpath, output, echo, scrape

so I'm very new to php. But with some help, I've figured out how to scrape a site if it has a tag identifier like h1 class=____

And even better, I've figured out how to output the precise word or value I want, as long as it's separated by a blank white space. So for example if a given tag name < INVENTORY > has an output of "30 balls," I can specify to echo[0], and only 30 will output. Which is great.

I'm running into an issue though, were I'm trying to extract a value that is not separated by a blank space. So what I mean is, let's say I want "-34.89," as the output (more precisely, whatever number is in that place holder on the site, since the numbers on the source site are likely changing over time).

But, my output I'm getting is "-34.89dowjonesstockchange". There's no blank space there.

What do I do to just output the -34.89? Or, whatever number may be in it's place on a given day. There must be some way to signify in that above output, to only output values [0,1,2,3,4,5] for ex, which would be -34.89 in terms of numbers of values.

The below is a test example on a website, that outputs words and values determined by " " blank space. Which is almost what I need, but missing this way of being even more precise.

```
// this function is a scraping function for ethereumchange
function getEthereumchange(){
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    // We don't want to bother with white spaces
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;


    $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $doc->recover = true;

    $doc->loadHTMLFile('https://coinmarketcap.com/');



    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $query = "//tr[@id='id-ethereum']";




    $entries = $xpath->query($query);
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        $result = trim($entry->textContent); 
        $ret_ = explode(' ', $result);
        //make sure every element in the array don't start or end with blank
        foreach ($ret_ as $key=>$val){
            $ret_[$key]=trim($val);
        }
        //delete the empty element and the element is blank "\n" "\r" "\t"
        //I modify this line
        $ret_ = array_values(array_filter($ret_,deleteBlankInArray));
            
        //echo the last element
        file_put_contents(globalVars::$_cache_dir . "ethereumchange", 
$ret_[7]);

    }
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use third party library you can use https://github.com/rajanrx/php-scrape

```
<?php

use Scraper\Scrape\Crawler\Types\GeneralCrawler;
use Scraper\Scrape\Extractor\Types\MultipleRowExtractor;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Create crawler
$crawler = new GeneralCrawler('https://coinmarketcap.com/');

// Setup configuration
$configuration = new \Scraper\Structure\Configuration();
$configuration->setTargetXPath('//table[@id="currencies"]');
$configuration->setRowXPath('.//tbody/tr');
$configuration->setFields(
    [
        new \Scraper\Structure\TextField(
            [
                'name'  => 'Name',
                'xpath' => './/td[2]/a',
            ]
        ),
        new \Scraper\Structure\TextField(
            [
                'name'  => 'Market Cap',
                'xpath' => './/td[3]',
            ]
        ),
        new \Scraper\Structure\RegexField(
            [
                'name'  => '% Change',
                'xpath' => './/td[7]',
                'regex' => '/(.*)%/'
            ]
        ),
    ]
);

// Extract  data
$extractor = new MultipleRowExtractor($crawler, $configuration);
$data = $extractor->extract();
print_r($data);
```

will print out following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Bitcoin
            [Market Cap] => $42,495,710,233
            [% Change] => -1.09
            [hash] => 76faae07da1d2f8c1209d86301d198b3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Ethereum
            [Market Cap] => $28,063,517,955
            [% Change] => -8.10
            [hash] => 18ade4435c69b5116acf0909e174b497
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Ripple
            [Market Cap] => $11,483,663,781
            [% Change] => -2.73
            [hash] => 5bf61e4bb969c04d00944536e02d1e70
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Litecoin
            [Market Cap] => $2,263,545,508
            [% Change] => -3.36
            [hash] => ea205770c30ddc9cbf267aa5c003933e
        )
   and so on ...
```

I hope that helps you :)

> Disclaimer: I am author of this library.

Answer (score 1):

if you only care about that change percentage, try this and remove the whole `foreach` section:

```
$query = "//tr[@id='id-ethereum']/td[contains(@class, 'percent-24h')]";
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

echo $entries->item(0)->getAttribute('data-usd'); //-5.15
```

here are the rest of the columns:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$market_cap = $xpath->query("//tr[@id='id-ethereum']/td[contains(@class, 'market-cap')]");
echo $market_cap->item(0)->getAttribute('data-usd'); //30574084827.1


$price = $xpath->query("//tr[@id='id-ethereum']/td/a[contains(@class, 'price')]");
echo $price->item(0)->getAttribute('data-usd'); //329.567

$circulating_supply = $xpath->query("//tr[@id='id-ethereum']/td/a[@data-supply]");
echo $circulating_supply->item(0)->getAttribute('data-supply'); //92770467.9991


$volume = $xpath->query("//tr[@id='id-ethereum']/td/a[contains(@class, 'volume')]");
echo $volume->item(0)->getAttribute('data-usd'); //810454000.0


$percent_change = $xpath->query("//tr[@id='id-ethereum']/td[contains(@class, 'percent-24h')]");
echo $percent_change->item(0)->getAttribute('data-usd'); //-3.79
```

Comment: well, actually i'm trying to make it so i can apply that to any value ideally. identified by number position in the output.

Comment: @Masteryogurt you're definitely better off explicitly targeting the fields you want. if they add a new column to the table tomorrow, your script will fail to work.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. Problem is, often these fields/tags carry a lot of data in them. very hard finding clean ones. typically I get by very well with the target by blank space php function above, just some things I'm trying to get I haven't been able to find with blank spaces. I guess the fact that on occasion, if something changes in source site I'll have to adjust a few numbers. for now, I can live with it.

Comment: but indeed, there are likely better practices for this.

Comment: if you have a second, okay if you don't, but i'm wondering if that logic/function can work for the below situation. view-source:https://www.bloomberg.com/research/sectorandindustry/overview/sectorlanding.asp   Getting stock sector info. like if it's possible to pull the first value. +1.14%    Having some difficulty seeing how to apply that coding in this situation

Comment: @Masteryogurt $cell = $xpath->query("//table[@id='sectorTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]");
echo $cell->item(0)->nodeValue;