# add truncated sentence to web scrape output PHP

Tags: php, xpath, truncate

Not great at this. I found some code that I've been able to manipulate to scrape data, and output it. However, some of the text that outputs is sometimes too long for my site, and I'm trying to find a way via php to add truncated "..." if a given output goes over a max amount of words. I think I found a potential solution, however can't get it to add the truncated effect. And CSS isn't going to do the trick, because my site doesn't have a fixed width.

```
    function getEthereumvalue(){
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    // We don't want to bother with white spaces
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $doc->recover = true;

    @$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://_____________/');

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $query = "//tr[@id='id-ethereum']";

    $entries = $xpath->query($query);
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        $result = trim($entry->textContent); 
        $ret_ = explode(' ', $result);
        //make sure every element in the array don't start or end with blank
        foreach ($ret_ as $key=>$val){
            $ret_[$key]=trim($val);
        }
        //delete the empty element and the element is blank "\n" "\r" "\t"
        //I modify this line
        $ret_ = array_values(array_filter($ret_, 'deleteBlankInArray'));

        //echo the last element
        file_put_contents(globalVars::$_cache_dir . "ethereumvalue", 
 $ret_[3]);
 $_cache_dir= strlen($in) > 8 ? substr($in,0,8)."..." : $in;
    }
}
```

I added this:

```
 $_cache_dir= strlen($in) > 8 ? substr($in,0,8)."..." : $in;
```

To the working code above on the last line. It doesn't break my code interestingly, but simply doesn't apply the effect.

Thanks so much for reading this/any help.

Comment: Who is `$in` ? from where do you get it?

Comment: The condition you added seems ok, make sure you subtract the number of dots from your index used in `substr`. You need to investigate the value of `$in` also the type of the variable.

Comment: @lauda Thanks for response. Oh. I see the in must be from the source code I found that example. Do you have any advice as to what variable I should replace with in? $ret?

Comment: Do a `var_dump` for `$ret_` that should be an array and see what contains, possible that you might need `$ret_[3]` .

Comment: This link may be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742687/php-scrapping-and-outputting-a-specific-value-or-number-in-a-given-tag/44753597#44753597